# How to switch to either c++_shared or c++_static with CMAKE?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

On android Studio trying to build a project with CPP code but it gave `gnustl_static is no longer supported.` error. From other answer I added following on build.gradle:

```
 ndk {
        moduleName = "app"
        stl = "stlport_static"
    }
```

but it doesn't work and shows this error message again. Tried [this link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html#variables) added `ANDROID_STL=c++_static` on `cmake{...}` but got following error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "G:/Applications/.../app/ANDROID_STL=c++_static" does not exist.
```

How to solve this error message on latest android studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `stl` property might have been available in the past. But nowadays you would specify the STL using the `arguments` property, e.g.:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Note that `c++_static` is the default when building for Android with cmake. So if that's the STL you want you don't need to specify it at all.

Comment: gave `Unsupported method: NativeArtifact.getSourceFolders().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.` . and after upgrading gradle it shows `Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;` error. Will update if solves.

Comment: @Rifat for error 'Unsupported method: NativeArtifact.getSourceFolders(). The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method'; plz try with latest gradle and gradle android plugin.

Comment: not specifying STL solved it. As it is stated in this answer I'm accepting it. Thanks everyone.